# Find degree of $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{-2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I'm studying for a qualifier and came upon this problem. Now my reasoning is that $\sqrt{-2} = i\sqrt{2}$ does not live in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and so $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{-2}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{-2}):\mathbb{Q}(i)][\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}]=2\cdot2=4$. Does this make sense? Further it seems that $\mathbb{Q}(i)=\mathbb{Q}[i]$ so that $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{-2}):\mathbb{Q}(i)]=2$ as well. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Looks quite correct to me, if you can convince your teacher and yourself that $\sqrt{-2}\notin\mathbb{Q}(i)$. You might also use $\sqrt{2}$ in place of $\sqrt{-2}$. The reason for this is that $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt2)=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{-2})$. And it is easier to convince anyone about $\sqrt2\notin\mathbb{Q}(i)$. After all, all the real numbers in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ are rational!

Comment: Thanks, that verified what I was wondering.

Answer (score 1):

You've certainly got everything right. Here's another way of thinking about it:

1) Is the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt{-2}$ still irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$? If so, what is it's degree?

That should answer both your questions, I think.

Comment: Well, I would argue that the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt{-2}$ is $x^2+2$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. Making $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{-2})$ a degree two extension of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: Right, that's precisely it. It also means you can then use the multiplicativity of extension degrees to conclude that $[\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{-2}):\mathbb{Q}] = 4$. I guess I just thought I'd suggest this way of thinking about it as while it is "obvious" that $\sqrt{-2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(i)$, there are examples where it is subtler and harder to tell. That is to say, I didn't mean to suggest that you had anything incorrect if I did!

Comment: Thanks, I felt confident with my answer but just wanted to fact check with others.

Comment: No problem, I've edited my answer to more reflect what I was going for. Cheers!

Comment: @user62108: Dear Awertheim, I just want to point out that proving that $x^2 + 2$ is irred. in $\mathbb Q(i)[x]$ and proving that $\sqrt{-2} \not\in \mathbb Q(i)$ are absolutely equivalent statments, so while this is a nice way to think about the problem, it is not a simplification.  (Unless you apply some non-trivial result to deduce that $x^2 + 2$ is irred. over $\mathbb Q(i)$, rather than working directly from the definition of irreducibility.  Eisenstein's criterion over $\mathbb Z[i]$ is one candidate method, but it doesn't apply here.)  Regards,

Comment: @MattE, my apologies for being so inarticulate these past several comments. You are indeed correct that they are equivalent, and I didn't mean to imply otherwise - I simply meant to say that showing that the minimal polynomial remains irreducible is the rigorous way to conclude what was deemed obvious. It seems like my comment might well be superfluous, though.